# How to automatically re-run different installed Android App whenever it stops running?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to make a very basic app that as long as it is running, it will detect on every frame update, whether a different app is running in the background (an app that isn't visible on the main screen area, just an icon at the top on the opposite side of the `battery/wifi/simcard` icons are when not in full screen. Hope that makes sense, don't know what that bar at the top is called.)

I have a check box, when checked in my apps layout, it will continuously re-launch the app back up whenever it closes automatically. When unchecked, it will will allow the app to close and stay closed as normal. This is all assuming the third party app I want to check and run was already installed manually.

it can run in the background even and do its thing even when the phone is locked or on sleep mode, which I can code that stuff on my own I'm convinced.

So here's the deal, I need two functions/methods/whatever. One that checks the status of whether an existing installed app is running (I guess by using the app id or something similar as the param), even if it is in that background as I mentioned, it doesn't need to check window focus, just whether its an existing process running.

The other function I need to run an app based on its id, like what I said about checking its running status.

Here's a mockup to fill in the hollow spots if I'm explaining this terribly, note I'm new to android java programming but i think I'm learning a little fast since I'm experienced with c++ already so it involves less to learn than being new to programming.

The code:

```
//check fires every step/update
If (CheckIfAppIsRunning("com.compamy.company") == False) { // or 0, whatever java does I don't have my pc or eclipse in front of me right now
    RunApp("com.company.example");
}
```

I haven't done this in a while but I'm positive this should be all I'll need on this one. Just a `CheckIfAppIsRunning()` and a `RunApp()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the concept of running and not running isn't that simple in android.

First of all, Android usually keeps apps processes around as long as possible, so even (stopped) apps can be running as a lightweight process incase the user wanted to relaunch the app.

Which makes it impossible to detect exactly what process is really running and what isn't.

but the good news is that android does background work in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) object that can be relaunched by other components.

So if I were you I'd try and use [Activity Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) and get a list of the running services. and compare them to the List of installed apps pulled from [Package Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) to identify what is running and what isn't.

Now assuming you want to relaunch a specific service, not all services have public interfaces to start them (public intent that is defined in the app's manifest.xml) so you might need to launch the whole app instead which means two things:

- it will be brought to the front, and whatever the user was doing will be interrupted.
- if the device in idle mode nothing will happen.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, many thanks!  Will test around and add my solution (my exact code snippet I'll write based on your helpful links) in an edit for anyone who'd find it useful. Cheers! :)